# Pandas Dataframes: Combining Columns from Two Global Datasets when the rows hold different Countries

Tags: python, pandas

My Problem is that these two CSV files have different countries at different rows, so I can't just append the column in question to the other data frame.

https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_recovered_global.csv

https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv

I'm trying to think of some way to use a for loop, checking every row, and add the recovered cases to the correct row where the country name is the same in both data frames, but I don't know how to put that idea in to code. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this a couple of ways:

#### Option 1: use `pd.concat` with `set_index`

```
pd.concat([df_confirmed.set_index(['Province/State', 'Country/Region']),
          df_recovered.set_index(['Province/State', 'Country/Region'])],
         axis=1, keys=['Confirmed', 'Recovered'])
```

#### Option 2: use `pd.DataFrame.merge` with an left join or outer join using `how` parameter

```
df_confirmed.merge(df_recovered, on=['Province/State', 'Country/Region'], how='left', 
                   suffixes=('_confirmed','_recovered'))
```

Using pd.read_csv from github raw format:

```
df_recovered = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_recovered_global.csv')

df_confirmed = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv')
```